# Merge ActionController::Parameters with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, actioncontroller, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 4, I can merge! StrongParams, but since rails 5 (beta1) merge! is not available. Which is the best way to do that in a controller

```
  params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
             name: 'Francesco',
             age:  22,
             role: 'admin'
         })
         params.merge!(city: "Los Angeles")
```

Answer (score 12):

As far as I can see [from the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4ff5f6a15bb8f89c07b396a81b825a4efaaecd29/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L569-L573), you have `merge` not `merge!`. In other words, it doesn't seem to be possible to modify the hash in place.

The following code will work:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
             name: 'Francesco',
             age:  22,
             role: 'admin'
         })
params = params.merge(city: "Los Angeles")
```

Comment: Any idea how to merge into a nested model parameters?

Comment: @W.M. sort of `params[:nested_params] = params[:nested_params].merge(...)`

Answer (score 2):

params.merge!(city: "Los Angeles") works with Rails5.0.1

[image]

In Rails 5: ActionController::Parameters Now Returns an Object Instead of a Hash.

so you must use params.permit(:city).to_h to access city.

For more details how ActionController::Parameters works in Rails5?

Ref: http://www.rortuts.com/ruby-on-rails/rails5-actioncontrollerparameters/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to anyone.

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :user_id, :color)
end
```

I want to merge color attribute with my custom color code or name. so to merge color attribute dynamically

Ininitialize params in rails 5 like this,

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(comment_params)
params = params.merge(color: "green")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
new_params = params.to_h.merge(city: "Los Angeles")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Comment: This  only works when (all or some) parameters have been permitted

Comment: It returns another error instead: undefined method `to_h' for #<User:0x0000000734f088> Did you mean? to_s